# Does IBKR offer free real time time and series data?

Tags: brokerage, interactive-brokers

I wanted to ask if IBKR offers free real time time and series data. I didn't subscribe to market data yet, I only have the default IBKR PRO account with not added subscribtions and I've looked at the time and sales table and I saw this:

[image]

Now, I can see that the data updates every second, **the question is**, why ? I didn't pay for this. **Why can I see the NBBO**. Afaik I have to pay for level 1 data. **Also, why is the data delayed by 2 to 3 seconds, how can I fix that ?**

Answer (score 0):

From [Market Data Fees](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/pricing/research-news-marketdata.php):

> By default, users will receive free delayed market data for available exchanges. If needed, users can subscribe to real-time streaming market data for the prices listed in the tables below. Once a subscription is active, the delayed market data will be replaced with the real-time quotes.

Comment: Yes, but they refer to level 1, level 2 data, etc.  The 'delayed' data they are talking about is delayed by 15 minutes, the time and sales data is, for some reason, only delayed by a couple of seconds (2-3 seconds). I still don't quite understand if I have to pay anything for real time, time and sales data and why it is delayed by only a couple of seconds.

Comment: I don't see where it specifies that. Is it not possible that quote data and order book data are both provided but delayed by different intervals?

Comment: If that's true, then what subscription do I need to pay for exactly to get real time 'time and sales' data ? Also, do you need what subscription I need to pay for to access the real time market data (NBBO, Candlesticks, Time and Sales) using their API ? Is there a special subscription for that or can I just get that data once I subscribe for the NBBO ?

Comment: That I don't know for sure - I see that there are different fees for different capabilities and exchanges, so it may depend on what exchanges you want to get data for.

Comment: I have three real time subscriptions with IBKR ($1.50 each).  That includes data for the AMEX, NYSE, NASDAQ and options (Total of $4.50 per month).